How to create array-based sequential numbering in Google Sheets based on adjacent column, skipping blanks?
In Google Sheets, how can I create an ARRAYFORMULA to generate sequential numbering in column B, only when adjacent C cell is not empty?

I want to start sequential numbering from  B10,
If a cell in column C is blank, numbering in B cell be skipped, and then it continues from the next non-empty C cell.

Example:



Column B
Column C




1
apple


2
mango


‎
‎


3
orange


4
peach



I have found formulas for sequential numbering that ignore blank cells in the adjacent column, but these formulas need to be dragged down whenever new rows are added.
I want to use ARRAYFORMULA so that it applies automatically to the entire range.
I tried using this formula generated by Claude:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C10:C<>"", ROW(C10:C) - ROW(C10) + 1, ""))

This formula returns a blank in B cell when the adjacent C cell is empty, but it continues the numbering. So, in the table, it would show 4 - oranges , and , 5 - peach.


Here's one approach which you may adapt accordingly:
=map(C2:C,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,counta(C2:Σ))))


Alternative to try just in case those blank cells in Column_C are not true blank cells (which gives ISBLANK(<blank cell>)=false)
=map(C2:C,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,let(Σ,C2:Σ,counta(filter(Σ,Σ<>""))))))


You can also try this formula:
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(MATCH(ROW(C2:C6),FILTER(ROW(C2:C6),C2:C6<>""),0),))


Here's the breakdown:
First, we create an Id by using the ROW Function:

Next, we filter the Ids based on the condition that Column C is not empty:

Finally, we use the MATCH Function to search for the Ids from the Filtered Ids to get the sequential number:

If we combine all of this and add the IFNA Function to replace the #N/A Errors with a blank, we'll get the solution proposed above:
    =ArrayFormula(IFNA(MATCH(ROW(C2:C6),FILTER(ROW(C2:C6),C2:C6<>""),0),))

